# Recovery problem

Tags: virtualbox

I am using virtual box 4.1.18 on windows 7 to work on Ubuntu 10.04. Recently i started upgrading it to 12.04, while upgrading i powered off the machine. When i restarted, it is not launching Ubuntu completely. It is at Ubuntu logo launching page and not going further. I didn't take any backup of my previous files, Please help me in recovering my files from VDI. I attached below log for reference.

```
VirtualBox (XP)COM Server 4.1.18 r78361 win.amd64 (Jun 5 2012 15:58:59) release log
00:00:00.016 main Log opened 2013-05-30T01:38:15.652067300Z
00:00:00.016 main OS Product: Windows 7
00:00:00.016 main OS Release: 6.1.7601
00:00:00.016 main Executable: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxSVC.exe
00:00:00.016 main Process ID: 5452
00:00:00.016 main Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:00.062 Loading settings file "C:\Users\Sriks/.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml" with version "1.12-windows"
00:00:00.062 usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:00:00.062 usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:00:00.655 VDInit finished
00:00:00.764 Loading settings file "C:\Users\Sriks\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu\Ubuntu.vbox" with version "1.12-windows"
00:00:00.936 Loading settings file "C:\Users\Sriks\VirtualBox VMs\ubuntu_12.04\ubuntu_12.04.vbox" with version "1.12-windows"
00:00:00.967 Loading settings file "C:\Users\Sriks\VirtualBox VMs\ubuntu_linux_crash\ubuntu_linux_crash.vbox" with version "1.12-windows"
00:00:10.452 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002) aIID={5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={Machine} aText={Machine is not locked for session (session state: Unlocked)}, preserve=false
00:00:11.092 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={Saved screenshot data is not available (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false
00:24:06.129 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:24:13.087 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:24:14.943 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:24:16.987 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:24:21.854 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:24:25.692 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:24:27.579 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:24:27.579 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:28:33.421 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:28:38.866 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:30:08.535 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:30:08.535 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
00:58:48.181 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002) aIID={5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={Machine} aText={Machine is not locked for session (session state: Unlocked)}, preserve=false
00:59:21.362 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={Saved screenshot data is not available (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false
03:31:43.910 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
03:31:50.681 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
03:31:52.615 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
03:31:54.035 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
03:31:54.035 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
03:31:55.017 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
03:31:55.017 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
03:31:55.548 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
03:31:55.548 USBPROXY usbLibDevCfgDrGet: DeviceIoControl 1 fail winEr (31)
03:35:02.453 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002) aIID={5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={Machine} aText={Machine is not locked for session (session state: Unlocked)}, preserve=false
03:35:03.435 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={Saved screenshot data is not available (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false
03:35:05.151 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002) aIID={5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={The machine is not mutable (state is Starting)}, preserve=false
03:49:32.221 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_VM_ERROR (0x80bb0003) aIID={5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={Machine} aText={Failed to get a console object from the direct session (Unknown Status 0x80BB0007)}, preserve=false
03:49:55.340 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={No storage device attached to device slot 0 on port 1 of controller 'IDE Controller'}, preserve=false
03:49:58.850 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002) aIID={5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={Machine} aText={Machine is not locked for session (session state: Unlocked)}, preserve=false
03:49:59.692 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={Saved screenshot data is not available (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false
03:50:00.847 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002) aIID={5eaa9319-62fc-4b0a-843c-0cb1940f8a91} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={The machine is not mutable (state is Starting)}, preserve=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> while upgrading i powered off the machine

This is the worst thing you can ever do while upgrading anything.

How to recover your files?

1. Make a new fresh Ubuntu Virtual Machine and attach the old VDI to it
   as a secondary hard disk (From VirtualBox's GUI -> Settings->
   Storage -> + Hard Disk)
2. Recover your files

Comment: Or just boot your machine with an Ubutu iso attached to the CD driver.